# Add Text to TextView while AsyncTask Running

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am learning `AsyncTask`. I want to add a TextView like **Loading....** while AyncTask Working. How can I do this

Below is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText et_bookInput;
private TextView tv_titleText;
private TextView tv_authorText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et_bookInput = findViewById(R.id.bookInput);
    tv_titleText = findViewById(R.id.titleText);
    tv_authorText = findViewById(R.id.authorText);

}

public void searchBooks(View view) {
    // Get the name of the book from the input field
    String queryString = et_bookInput.getText().toString();
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if(inputMethodManager != null){
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
    new FetchBook(tv_titleText, tv_authorText).execute(queryString);

}
```

Comment: Possible to add the code for FetchBook? Have you tried using the onPreExecute and onPostExecute functions? Also, AsyncTask is not the preferred way to do asynchronous tasks on Android anymore, Coroutines are recommended by Android.

Comment: As per my knowledge, Corountines is Kotlin Library so can I use it in java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
 tv_authorText.setText("");
 tv_titleText.setText(R.string.loding);
```

I assumed that at `tv_titleText` you want to add loading Text.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested you code and you need to set the `loading` Text just inside your `searchBooks(View view)`

```
TextView.setText("Loading...")
```